# Proper representation of ArrayList<Object> of Java in C++

Tags: java, c++, oop

In Java, I use

```
ArrayList<Object> contents = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

to hold generic types, and elements are not meant to be of the same type.

For example, I did things like :

```
int n = 1991;
String str = "mfso";
contents.add(n);
contents.add(str);
```

Now, I would like to do the same thing in C++, but I found nothing alike. 
I tried `void**, but it is very C-like and too hard to harness. I want a more OO flavor solution.

I hope you can show me different solutions and briefly tell me the pros&cons.

Thanks in advance

KeCen Zhou

Comment: To be honest, storing **any** type in a container is not particularly OO. You end up having to make a lot of `if()` type branches that OO is supposed to avoid. To be OO you really need the types stored in the container to be strongly related so each type ***is a*** variety of some common base type interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ doesn't have such a "universal base-class" like Java's `Object` class. So, this mechanism has to be created some other way.

For a truly "anything" container, the only general solution is to use something like `boost::any` from the [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/any.html) library (which might also be supported by some compilers as `std::experimental::any`, [as described here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any)). There is obviously overhead to using this, but I assume this is something you are prepared to live with.

Here is how you could use it:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include <boost/any.hpp>

int main() {
  std::vector< boost::any > contents;

  int n = 1991;
  std::string str = "mfso";
  contents.emplace_back(n);
  contents.emplace_back(str);

  for(auto& x : contents) {
    if( x.type() == typeid(int) )
      std::cout << " Int: " 
                << boost::any_cast< int >(x) << std::endl;
    else if( x.type() == typeid(std::string) )
      std::cout << " String: " 
                << boost::any_cast< std::string& >(x) << std::endl;
  };
};
```

Ideally, you should avoid using something like `boost::any` if you can solve your problem some other way. For example, if all types of objects are related (or can be related) through some base-class, then you should use that. Or, if you have a limited number of types that you expect to store in the container, then you can use something like `boost::variant` instead (see [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think a rather direct translation from Java to C++ is impossible, and I shouldn't have assumed so.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use a **template**. A template is a C++ language construct that allows the compiler to generate multiple versions of a class type or a function by allowing parameterized type (mine).

```
template <class Obj>
class Foo
{
   private:
      Obj n;
      int x;
      //... more variables etc..

}
```

Implementation:

```
Foo<string> t;
Foo<yourObject> s;
t.yourmethod(someParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the overhead of boost in your project (which is quite big, if you ask me) you can do the following:

```
std::vector<void*> contents;

int n = new int(9);
std::string s = new string("hello");
contents.push_back(n);
contents.push_back(s);

// get the contents
if (typeid(*contents[0]).name() == std::string("int")) {
    std::cout << "contents[0] is an int" << std::endl;
}
// so on and so forth
```

Note that this is not the C++ way of doing things. If you're going to try to write Java inside C++ you're going to have a hard time, so I suggest learning the idiomatic way of doing things.

Comment: That technique is not portable since the string returned by type_info::name is implementation defined.